# Selenium to check text in a list

Tags: c#, list, selenium, verification

I have a list of elements as shown in the code. And I am changing it to Array. Before my application starts, the user will enter some text in a text box.

C# Code:

```
IList<IWebElement> namelist = driver2.FindElements(By.TagName("SPAN"));
namelist.ToArray();
```

What I want to do is : to check whether text entered by the user is present in that list.

Suppose the user enters `"String Text"`, then I need selenium to check whether "String Text" is present in this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your array of elements to `List` and then verify presence of text with [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) function from `System.Linq` namespace:

```
// Get text entered by the user
string checkText = "String Text";

if (namelist.ToList().Any(span => span.Text.Contains(checkText)))
{
    // List contains text
}
else
{
    // List does not contain text
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrii. But I could get an error like "Error 1 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' does not contain a definition for 'InnerText' and no extension method 'InnerText' accepting a first argument of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

What is this? What mistake I am doing here?

Comment: Could you please look into this issue too??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202452/selenium-to-click-on-a-javascript-button-corresponding-to-a-text

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal Add `nameslist.ToList().Find(span => span.Text.Contains(checkText)).Click();` into block under `if` condition. It is not clear how you find buttons by content in your another question.

Comment: But the tagname for button is not SPAN. Then, any change in your answer?

Comment: No, What I meant was using your above given answer i found a matching content. Now,  I want selenium to click on the button present in this content (it is present on other contents too)

Comment: :Your above answer is not working in some moment. While some moment it works as expected..Why it is so?

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal Load timeout of web page may be a reason - you need to wait somehow till control appears or timeout exprires. If control is present and was found - code should work.

Comment: Ok..Any idea on my other question?

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal You need to find child elements of span that you found - see this [Automation blog article](http://automationhints.blogspot.com/2012/07/find-child-elements-selenium-web-driver.html). Looks like code there is not in C# - you will need to port it yourself.