# Selenium to click on a javascript button corresponding to a text

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a lot of buttons in my web page and that too are javascript buttons. All those buttons have same TagName, but different id. But I cant use ID since I cant predict which button has to be clicked.

[image]

Selenium will search for a content (Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201880/selenium-to-check-text-in-a-list)) and if could find the content, then it must click on the respective button. How can it be achieved?

Any comments would be really helpful and appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This will find a button based on the displayed text on the button and click it.

```
var loggout = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Logg ut"));
loggout.Click();
```

Or you can change it to;

```
By.Id()
By.CssSelector()
By.Name()
...
```

Comment: I dont think it will work since the link text in button is same in all buttons. Anyway I will try it out..

Comment: I know all those things. But Please see my question again. And I tried your's..But sorry, it failed

Comment: If you got a list like
`IList<IWebElement> namelist = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("SPAN"));`

Can't you just do `namelist.Single(func).Click()` ?

Comment: I couldn't follow you..sorry..could you please show me an example?